# How do you check for the existence of a field in an Cloudwatch JSON filter?

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-cloudwatch

This is a terraform setup:

```
resource "aws_cloudwatch_log_metric_filter" "account-query-time" {
  name           = "${local.name_prefix}-AccountQueryTime"
  pattern        = "{ $.message = \"AccountQuery_70fed564\"  }"
  log_group_name = yaddayadda

  metric_transformation {
    name      = "AccountQueryTime"
    namespace = "Accounts"
    value     = "$.time"
  }
}
```

Logs have JSON objects like `{"message": "AccountQuery_70fed564", "time": 320, "units", "microseconds"}`

Relevant portion is `pattern = "{ $.message = \"AccountQuery_70fed564\"  }"`. Can I make sure the field exists as part of the pattern? Will the filter only pick fields that are valid for its metric transform?

I'd like to make sure that this metric will not add in messages that are missing the time field. The docs have [NOT EXISTS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/FilterAndPatternSyntax.html) but don't have EXISTS by itself.

Tried:

- `&& $.time`
- `&& $.time EXISTS`
- `&& !!$.time`

Is it not necessary to check for the existence of a field? Seems safer to confirm that it is there before you go and add it to your metric...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the inverse of the exists call, you need to both check if it has data and if it is null.

I haven't found a way to do this in one call, like the doesn't exist call [from the Docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/FilterAndPatternSyntax.html#matching-terms-events)

```
{ $.SomeOtherObject NOT EXISTS }
```

However if you do both the following, it evaluates to being the invese of the above:

```
{ $.SomeOtherObject = * EXISTS || $.SomeOtherObject IS NULL }
```

That should get you all instances where SomeOtherObject exists in your context, be it null or set to a value

Answer (score 1):

Looks like this will do it:

`"{ $.message = \"AccountQuery_70fed564\" && $.units = * && $.time = *  }"`